# Using Reinforcement Learning to Predict Prices

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am using Boston Housing Data, I am using various model provided by keras and Sklearn to predict the house prices.

I want to know from an expert here on Stack Overflow, if I can use keras-rl or Re-inforcement learning to build a prediction model.

If so, how can i do so and integrate that in my NN code. I am looking over papers and kernels over kaggle and browsing, but unfortunately, could not find such implementation. The provided examples are solving games and balancing poles only, like playing games using RL.

TIA

Comment: could you please explain what the difference between Supervised learning and Reinforcement learning is because i think you are making a little confusion here between those two.

Comment: Sure, Supervised, like my problem - target is known and RL is like learning from previous instances

Comment: Can I add something like Markov decision process

Comment: Well here is the confusion. RL will learn by interacting with the environement. It will learn after a certain time. We learn the optimal strategy by sampling actions and then observing which one leads to our desired outcome. This can't be applied here because Regression Is a Supervised problem. Using RL here won't be usefull as you already have the datas you need to overcome the problem

Comment: @Alexis Thanks a ton, I think, you are right and I am wrong. but can I ask you a last question like, can I use it for time series model, stock prediction or predicting life of an object, based on historical data

Comment: that's the thing =) RL is used when you can't store all the datas so you do the "try and learn method". If you have enought datas to find a solution then RL is not needed. BUT if there is a lot of human interaction and as you can't sample all the human actions, then you'll use RL. I m sure you can do it for market places, not for predicting place but for saling or buying stockes automaticly for example. Problem based on historical Datas are supervised and as such don't require RL.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this Alexis. Any link you can share with me, which hits to my question, I want to learn more and dont want to bother you more on the same. I am curios.

Comment: http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf here you go. This is the best thing right now. Recommended by erwan le pennec (great great teacher in this field)

Comment: @Alexis Actually here is the [book webpage](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html) and there is a link to the final soon-to-be-published version of the book. Thanks for referring to that. I was not aware that there is a second edition.